# Drupal 7 - Construct clean URL from form post

Tags: forms, drupal, menu, drupal-7

I am creating a custom module in Drupal 7 that is a job search. I am wanting to make it so you can specify a clean URL to perform the search like so:

www.example.com/job-board/cardiology/california

Where "cardiology" is the "specialty" variable and "california" is the "location" variable.

now I know how to do this as far as mapping the variables in my hook_menu and accessing the variables. The problem is how do I create a search form that creates the clean url when you submit it? In other words if I had this:

```
<form method="get" action="job-board">
  <select name="specialty">
    <option value="cardiology">Cardiology</option>
    <option value="some_other_value">Some Other Value</option>
  </select>
  <select name="location">
    <option value="california">California</option>
    <option value="some_other_state">Some Other State</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and I submit it, it will go to www.example.com/job-board?specialty=cardiology&location=california instead of www.example.com/cardiology/california. How can I make the form construct a clean URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create that form using Drupal's Form API and assign a custom submit callback to it.

In that submit callback, you can perform validation and if everything is OK, redirect the user to the appropriate URL.

See the source code of [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) modules, specifically one related to Form API in order to learn more about it.

In short, here's what you would do:

```
/**
 * Sample form.
 */
function MYMODULE_sample_form() {
  $form['specialty'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Specialty'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['state'] = array(
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
      'california' => t('California')
    ),
  );
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Submit the form'));

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Sample form submit processing.
 */
function MYMODULE_sample_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $specialty = $form_state['values']['specialty'];
  $state     = $form_state['values']['state'];

  drupal_goto($specialty . '/ ' . $state);
}
```